# How to add title to mapbox <iframe> embed

Tags: web-mapping, tilemill, mapbox

I am embedding a map I made in Tilemill/Mapbox onto a Wix website. Items of the map such as legend, title, and description are not automatically included in the embed. I learned how to add the legend by simply adding ,legend, in the code below. However, I do not know how to add the title and description of the map as you see it here: https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/yolivens.hgck7b4h/page.html?secure=1#4/40.85/-94.48

Here is my current  code:

[image]

What would I need to do to add the title and description? I am above all concerned about the title.

Comment: In case these instructions from mapbox make more sense to you than they did for me: https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/maps/#embeds

Comment: You might change the iframe snippet from an image to text, so that the src URL can be selected/copied (to make it easier for those who might want to help).

Answer (score 1):

Use the good URL (the one that shows the description and the title) as the src link in your iframe.

Like this:

```
<iframe width='100%' height='500px' frameborder='0' src='https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/yolivens.hgck7b4h/page.html?secure=1#4/40.85/-94.48'></iframe>
```